# resultSet is null, how ever mysql query is correct

Tags: java, jdbc

I have problem with my java code (Resultset is null). It was working on localhost until I have tried remote Mysql scalegrid hosting . The most interesting is that, if I use Mysql Workbench query works fine and returns all rows. What I am doing wrongly.

I have tried to commit my table manually;

`Query (SELECT * FROM ShopDatabase.DATA)` works fine;

```
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String userName = "App";
        String password = "AppShopData+2";
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://SG-ShopDatabase-821-master.servers.mongodirector.com:3306/ShopDatabase";
        try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userName, password)){
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();


            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ShopDatabase.DATA where product_name = 'Хлеб';");

            while(resultSet.next()){
                System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                System.out.println("----------------");
            }



            }



    }
}
```

Comment: I'd remove the ; from "...`'Хлеб';", though I'm not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: 'Хлеб' is a value in colomn product_name and I would like to get Mysql row with this value

Comment: I would spend the 2 minutes it takes to properly format /indent when asking others to spend their time to help me with a problem....

Comment: There are no errors in the logs for this query, like mentioned by Eran regarding the ";" in the end of the query that is not necessary?

Comment: Hello @dS, please take the time to properly format the code in your post.

Comment: @dS try to change `= 'Хлеб';` to `= 'Хлеб'`

Comment: `executeQuery` should never return null. It will either return a - possibly empty - result set, or it will throw an exception. And if it does return `null` than it is a bug in the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the correct MySQL connection and that there is indeed a column value 'Xлеб' there:

- Remove ";" at the end of the query and check
- If the above won't work, eliminate possible internationalization issues (whatever they can be): Store "Bread" instead of Xлеб and see whether you have results (Xлеб is bread in Russian). Of course you'll need to adjust the query correspondingly

Comment: Hello, so many thanks to you it worked, fine I just put insted "Xлеб" "Bread" and it worked! Is it problem with encoding?

Comment: Probably yes but its hard to tell what exactly happens. I suggest you to work with PreparedStatement and use the product name value as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;` at the end of the query:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM ShopDatabase.DATA where product_name = 'Хлеб'");
```